# How can I add initcap function in ignite sql?

Tags: sql, ignite

I need the initcap funtion which capitalizes the initial letters but it seems like ignite doesn't support that function by default. Can I define the function using a query or do I need to implement it in my Java application? Or is there a smarter way to achieve the same functionality using upper and lower?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite 2.13 supports initcap function, to use it you should enable [calcite-based sql engine](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-calcite). If you use earlier version or not ready to enable beta functionality you should [implement](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/custom-sql-func) initcap manually in your Java application.